# Передвижение объекта в массиве

Tags: ios, objective-c

Как передвинуть любой объект из этого массива?

```
self.images = [NSMutableArray array];
NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager new];
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [manager enumeratorAtPath:[bundle bundlePath]];

for (NSString* name in enumerator) {
    if ([name hasSuffix:@"PawnWhite.png"]) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
            UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
            [self.images addObject:image];
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < self.images.count; i++) {

    CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(75.f, 0);

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(84.f + myPoint.x * i, 870.f, 75.f, 75.f)];

    self.imagesView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    self.imagesView.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:i];

    [self.view addSubview:self.imagesView];
    [valueView addSubview:self.view];
```

Выделить отдельное *view* и изменить его местоположение?

Comment: передвинуть имеется ввиду изменить индекс в массиве, или передвинуть вью по экрану?

Comment: Передвинуть вью по экрану. Там картинки с заданным фреймом, надо эти картинки кодом подвинуть.

Answer (score 3):

можно каждому imageView назначить тэг

```
self.imagesView.tag = i+1; //не использовать тэг=0
```

и искать их по тэгу и изменять фрейм

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:SOMETAG] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
```

либо создать еще один массив и в него сложить все imagesView и когда надо изменить фрейм какого то imageView у него будет тот же индекс, что и у image

```
[[self.imageViews objectAtIndex:[self.images objectAtIndex:SOMEINDEX]] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
```